# What is the spring cloud services version compatible to Spring boot version 2.7.11?

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-cloud

I am developing a spring boot application. I'am using the latest version of spring boot(2.7.11) for Java 8.
I have added all my logic but cannot start my application properly.

The issue is when I'am trying to run the spring boot application it says:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener and org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
```

In the pom.xml file

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>      </spring-cloud-services.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>               </spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

I beleive if I correctly enter the correct spring-cloud-services.version and spring-cloud.version the application will run. But what is the correct version numbers for the above for Spring boot version 2.7.11?

Comment: https://start.spring.io  is fast & reliable reference (our friend!).... it proposes: `<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.6</spring-cloud.version>` for `2.7.11` ( `2022.0.2` for `3.0.6` ;) ..but what is `spring-cloud-services.version` ?? ;(;(

Comment: The dependecy that i was using for pom.xml is a old dependency. The new dependency to implement for circuit breaker in pom.xml is as follows:

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

<spring-cloud-services.version></spring-cloud-services.version>   This is one of the dependencies that needs to updated in property tag to implement circuit breaker.....but i am having difficulty finding the correct version number.

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**